# how two different webmethod can be called at the same time?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 different web method one receive a string and save it in Public static string on web service and another one is displaying the Public static string on .aspx page which make a call every 30 second to get the updated string on web service. but what is happening is that when i up date the string the page still display the old Public static string . what can i do any Idea please?

Comment: There are better ways to store state. Is it one string per server, or one per whole web site (if it's multi server) or one per user, or something else?

Comment: yes is one string per server.

Comment: update ur current code....

Comment: Ah, hang on: is this MVC? Try setting an [OutputCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.aspx) attribute on your controller to disable caching or set it to something small, e.g. 5 seconds. Or if it's not MVC try @OutputCache on your .asmx.